# Facebook keyword statistics in more details

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to find the way to get detailed keyword statistics from the facebook API like here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights,

But there are 2 problems: to query this you need to be a facebook partner, and they are using FQL for this which will not be supported after API v2.0

Can anybody advise some currently supported API in facebook for this, like https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/keywordstats/v2.3, but with more detailed data breakdown(having age, gender, ...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's none you can use if you don't have access to the Keyword Insights API. Public post search for example has been deprecated with Graph API v2.0.